# Why is there a scrollbar for the hidden div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to slide in a DIV from the right but for some reason it is adding a horizontal scrollbar which I want to prevent.

Here is my JSFiddle link: [**DIV Slider**](http://jsfiddle.net/2vfLtbs3/)

HTML:

```
    <div id="slideOut" class="clearfix">
    <div id="slideContent">
        You ain't seen me, right?
    </div>
    <div id="slideClick">

    </div>
</div>
```

How do I get rid of the scrollbar from the bottom so it is hidden and slides out when the orange part is pressed?

Comment: `body {overflow:hidden}` ?

Comment: You could add overflow:hidden on the body element, but that could introduce other issues.

Comment: That's what I am trying to avoid and wanting to add it to a DIV?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the `slideOut` from `position: absolute` to `position: fixed`, as it will not add an overflow to the body...

http://jsfiddle.net/2vfLtbs3/4/

Answer (score 1):

This will fix your specific example:

```
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2vfLtbs3/3/)

not sure what other issues it might cause down the line though.

Comment: Instead of BODY can I do it specifically on a DIV?

Comment: What happens if he has other content on his page that's wider than the viewport?

Comment: @j08691 that's why I added the last line in my answer